# Lax vs Strict for Set-Cookie HTTP header and CSRF

Tags: http, cookies, csrf, same-origin-policy, setcookie

I was just reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie:

> Lax: The cookie is not sent on cross-site requests, such as calls to
> load images or frames, but is sent when a user is navigating to the
> origin site from an external site (e.g. if following a link). This is
> the default behavior if the SameSite attribute is not specified.

If this is the default, then doesn't this mean CSRF attacks can't happen?
If someone loads a malicious website that runs Javascript in the background to make a simple POST request to a website the victim is currently logged into, then the default behaviour is that the cookie won't be sent, right?

Also, why would someone choose to use Strict over Lax?
Why would you ever want to prevent a user's browser sending a cookie to the origin website when navigating to that website, which is what Strict does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSRF attacks are still possible when `SameSite` is `Lax`. It prevents the cross-site `POST` attack you mentioned, but if a website triggers an unsafe operation with a `GET` request then it would still be possible. For example, many sites currently trigger a logout with a `GET` request, so it would be trivial for an attacker to log a user out of their session.

The standard [addresses this](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-05#section-5.3.7.1) directly:

> Lax enforcement provides reasonable defense in depth against CSRF
> attacks that rely on unsafe HTTP methods (like "POST"), but does not
> offer a robust defense against CSRF as a general category of attack:
>
> 1. Attackers can still pop up new windows or trigger top-level
>    navigations in order to create a "same-site" request (as
>    described in section 5.2.1), which is only a speedbump along the
>    road to exploitation.
> 2. Features like `<link rel='prerender'>` can be
>    exploited to create "same-site" requests without the risk of user
>    detection.

Given that, the reason why someone would use `Strict` is straightforward: it prevents a broader class of CSRF attacks. There's a tradeoff, of course, since it prevents some ways of using your site, but if those use cases aren't important to you then the tradeoff might be justified.

Comment: But if the app is ReSTful, then the GET requests will be safe and idempotent. So it shouldn't matter that the cookie is sent with the request, because the only thing that should happen is data is returned, which can't be viewed because of the Same-Origin-Policy. I haven't heard of websites using GET to provide logout functionality before?
I still don't understand your last point, how can you create a CSRF attack if the user's browser is navigating to the origin website?

Comment: @DavidKlempfner: But there's no requirement that apps be "ReSTful", and the original HTTP specification doesn't require `GET` methods to be safe. I don't understand your last question (I didn't say anything about the origin server), but the point is straightforward: if `Lax` allows some CSRF attacks, and those attacks are prevented by `Strict`, then the reason to use `Strict` is to be more resistant to CSRF attacks.

Comment: Say you navigate to a website from a "bad" website by clicking on a hyperlink, why does it matter that the cookie is sent in that request (using Lax)?

Comment: @DavidKlempfner: If that cookie identifies and authorizes the user, then the malicious site can take actions on behalf of the user. Let's say a site has an endpoint that will delete all of the logged-in user's data on a `GET` request. If the site uses `Lax`, then the malicious site can mount a successful CSRF attack and delete the data. If the site uses `Strict`, it can't. Of course, that would be a bad and hopefully uncommon design, which is why `Lax` is good enough ("provides reasonable defense in depth") in most cases.